# Assigning Labels to ADC and DWI Images for Prostate Cancer Classification

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification, medical-imaging

I'm working on a prostate cancer classification task using ADC and DWI images in .nii format, and I have access to the disease status of each patient (positive or negative). My goal is to label these images for classification purposes. Here are my questions:

1. Label Type: What type of labels do I need to assign to the ADC and DWI images? Should I use a binary label (0 for negative, 1 for positive) for each patient?
2. Python Labeling: How can I efficiently label a large dataset of ADC and DWI images in Python based on the known disease status of each patient? Do you have any sample code or suggestions for automating this process?

I appreciate any guidance or code examples to help me label these images accurately for my classification task.